# Simple texturing in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to texture a 3D sphere I created. I am having difficulties understanding How textures works. They way I understand it is a picture file that "wraps" a 3D object. I found some tutorial online but If there is a really simple one to get me started that will be nice.
I am usind OpenGL 3+ on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as it gets. [Link.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texturing_a_Sphere)

Should be very easy to understand, if you don't then simply conduct further research.

Answer (score 1):

opengl redbook is a good source of knowledge for this:

http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/chapter09.html

basicly texturing any geometry requires you to specify for each vertex additional coordinates from your bitmap space. Since bitmaps are 2D you use two dimensional coordinates u,v. Your video card will extrapolate those coordinates and while rendering triangles from your verticies will put appropriate texels (texture pixels) from your bitmap. u,v coordinates for more complex geometry should be either calculated from code or be put manually in some 3D software like Blender.